# Can someone improve my collision detection code, it doesn't work properly ,as even when the mouse is not on the circle, it counts as being on it

Tags: java, processing

It's basically a simple game, in that, when the mouse pointer is within the circle, it adds one to the score. I'm new to processing and tried to create this simple game.

Here's the code:

```
float dist;
float score;
float x;
float y;
float ran;
float a;
float b;
void setup(){
  
  size(800,600);
  background(0);
  score = 0;
}
 

void draw(){
  
  background(0);
  text("score: "+score,600,20);
  
  x = random(800);
  y = random(600);
  
  circle_(x,y);
  if ( (abs(mouseX - x) <= 200) && (abs(mouseY - y) <= 200 )) { // algorithm for checking whether mouse inside the circle or not
    score = score + 1;
  }   
}

void circle_(float x,float y){
  delay(1000);
  circle(x,y,50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems here: first, you're checking 200 pixels where it should be 25 (as in 25 being half the diameter of the circle). But this is the easy one. The real issue is with the `delay(1000);` line.

That's the real pain.

It means that your program "sleeps" for about 1000/1001 seconds. While the mouse can go around the screen, this one just isn't listening. It's waiting.

You can track time in Processing with the `millis()` method. It gives you how many milliseconds have passed since you started running the sketch. I ninja coded you a couple lines to keep track of time and teleport the circle every 1 second. Here's the code:

```
float score;
float x;
float y;
int respawnCircle;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  background(0);
  score = 0;
}


void draw() {
  background(0);
  text("score: "+score, 600, 20);
  if (millis() > respawnCircle) {
    changeCircleCoordinates();
  }

  circle_(x, y);
  if ((abs(mouseX - x) <= 25) && (abs(mouseY - y) <= 25 )) { // using 25 as it's half the circle's diameter
    score = score + 1;
    // if you want the circle to change place right when you get one point uncomment the next line
    // changeCircleCoordinates();
  }
}

void changeCircleCoordinates() {
  respawnCircle = millis() + 1000;
  x = random(800);
  y = random(600);
}

void circle_(float x, float y) {
  //delay(1000); // this is why your collision detection wasn't working: the program is sleeping for about 1000/1001 milliseconds... you have to be very lucky to be on target at just the right time
  circle(x, y, 50);
}
```

Hope it helps. Have fun!